# Как исправить проблему с подключением bass dll к c++ builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, bass.dll

Пытаюсь подключить bass dll к проекту в c++ builder. Скачал архив с .dll, .h и .lib. Закинул в папку с проектом. Подключил через Project -> add to project все 3 файла. До подключения не видит функций(ожидаемо), а после при сборке выдаёт: 
[image: ошибка при сборке]
 В коде написал `#pragma comment(lib,"bass.lib")` и `#include "bass.h"`. Пробовал сконвертировать через coff2omf, но выдаёт, что уже сконвертировано, да и писало бы тогда, что не тот формат omf в ошибке в builder-е, а выдаёт это. Ccылку на архив с файлами bass dll прикреплю. Может быть какой-то файл битый. Как решить проблему?
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gqfMEwtZp5HbDO5PTxpKgiZENl7KndCl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib,"bass.lib")` - почему за такое не бьют по рукам? Освойте make, ninja, cmake или другую систему сборки (предпочтительнее cmake)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я лазил по форумам в поиске решения проблемы. там было указано добавлять эту строку. C++ - не мой основной язык

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Круто, а проблему как решить?

Comment: я уже написал как - такие "проблемы" решаются с помощью системы сборки. Берете любую, желательно `cmake`, который по-факту стал стандартом в этой области, и используете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё дело в том, что путь(не папка) до проекта содержит не латинские символы. Перенёс папку в корень диска - собралось.